# using firebase to user signup activity in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am trying to do a signup, but when i am trying to save the data into  , `Firebase Database`its not working.

I have added all the dependencies and internet permission in `Manifest`.

Please tell me what i am doing wrong, below is my basic code:

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {


private EditText mUserNameField;
private EditText mUserEmailField;
private EditText mUserPasswordField;
private Button mUserRegisterButton;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private ProgressDialog mProgress;
private DatabaseReference mDataBase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    mDataBase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    mProgress=new ProgressDialog(this);

    mUserNameField=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameField);
    mUserEmailField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userEmailField);
    mUserPasswordField=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.userpasswordField);
    mUserRegisterButton=(Button) findViewById(R.id.signupB3);

    mUserRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            startRegister();
        }
    });



    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}

private void startRegister() {

    final String name=mUserNameField.getText().toString().trim();
    String email=mUserEmailField.getText().toString().trim();
    String password=mUserPasswordField.getText().toString().trim();

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(email)&& !TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {

        mProgress.setMessage("Signing Up...");
        mProgress.show();

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                    String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                    DatabaseReference current_user_db = mDataBase.child(user_id);
                    current_user_db.child("name").setValue(name);
                    current_user_db.child("image").setValue("default");
                    mProgress.dismiss();

                    Intent mainIntent=new Intent(SignUp.this,CreateTour.class);
                    mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(mainIntent);
                }
            }
        });
    }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btnSignup;
    TextView btnLogin,btnForgotPass;
    EditText input_email,inpur_pass;
    RelativeLayout sign_up;

    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    Snackbar snackbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);


        btnSignup =(Button)findViewById(R.id.sign_button_register);
        btnLogin=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.signup_btn_login);
        btnForgotPass=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.signup_btn_forgot_pass);
        input_email=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.singup_email);
        inpur_pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.sign_password);
        sign_up=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.sign_up);

        btnSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnLogin.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnForgotPass.setOnClickListener(this);

        //init FireBase
        auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.getId()==R.id.signup_btn_login){
            startActivity(new Intent(Signup.this,MainActivity.class));
        }else if(v.getId()==R.id.signup_btn_forgot_pass){
            startActivity(new Intent(Signup.this,ForgotPass.class));
        }else if(v.getId()==R.id.sign_button_register){
            SignUpUser(input_email.getText().toString(),inpur_pass.getText().toString());
        }

    }

    private void SignUpUser(String email, String passeord) {

        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passeord).
                addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(!task.isSuccessful()){
                        snackbar=Snackbar.make(sign_up,"Error"+task.getException(),Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                    else {
                        snackbar=Snackbar.make(sign_up,"Register Successfully",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
                        snackbar.show();
                    }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

This  code is work perfectly.
You needs too include j son file on your project which is generated by Fire-base when you register your project on Fire-base.